# How to close entire browser on button click?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-development-server

I want to close my browser entirely  (chrome) on button click, I am able to do close a single tab using window.close(); what to do if want to close entire browser. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can't. It would (at best) be *incredibly* irritating and a quickly become a popular pastime of script kiddies if JS programmers could close every browser tab in a window just by someone visiting a webpage you could put some JS on.

People do have browser tabs that are none of your business and which they do care about keeping open.